# Lucene.net "DeleteDocuments" is not deleting documents

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net, lucene

I recently updated Lucene.net from nuget and DeleteDocuments stopped working. The following code is similar to what I am doing ... This is copied from "orchard cms". I noticed similar questions but the solutions are not relevant to my case. Anyone facing the same problem?

```
public void Delete(string indexName, IEnumerable<int> documentIds) {
    documentIds = documentIds.ToArray();

    if (!documentIds.Any()) {
        return;
    }

    using(var writer = new IndexWriter(indexName, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29), false, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)) {
        var query = new BooleanQuery();

        try {
            foreach (var id in documentIds) {
                query.Add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("id", id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))), Occur.SHOULD));
            }

            writer.DeleteDocuments(query);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.Error(ex, "An unexpected error occured while removing the documents [{0}] from the index [{1}].", String.Join(", ", documentIds), indexName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing an exception thrown?  Or does the method run successfully, but the documents you want to remove are still showing up in searches?  Also, do you see search results when you search with the same query you create here?

Comment: yeah, it runs successfully with no exception but when i run a query, the document is still there ...

Comment: Okay, and when you search with the query you've constructed in the code provided above, do you get results?

Comment: Yes... my intent it to update existing document, I delete existing one and add new document ... in my next search, i get two documents for the same id ... therefore, deleteDocument never deletes ...

Comment: Right.  What I'm getting at, I suspect something is wrong with the query.  Deleting by query simply runs the query as a search, and deletes all the returned documents.  If you run that exact query, I suspect you will see no results, thus the reason none of them are being deleted.  I would guess an analysis problem, or perhaps the "id" field is not indexed, something like that.